# linux service that starts an application in C# which reads from a tcp port and launch a GTK Window

Tags: c#, linux, sockets, shell, mono

I'm coding an app for linux (ubuntu 11.04) with C# and mono. This app is a server that reads a message (an url) from a tcp port (9898) which is sent by a Client that I made. The Server receives the URL an pops up a window (gtk Window) where I embed the HTML code from the URL with WebKit. Everything works fine when I execute the program, but I need this app running at startup, so I made a shell script that is run when the computer boots up. This script executes this line "mono NetworkServer.exe &". When I turn on my computer the process is alive and the NetworkServer.exe is running, but if I try to connect a Client the program crashes when it tries to create the window. If I start|restart the script manually everything works fine, so the problem is when the app is launched when the system is booting up.

This is the script (I removed some functionality to make it simpler):

```
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:             visitord
# Required-Start:       $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:        $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:        2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:         0 1 6
# Short-Description:    Create a deamon that initializes the NetworkServer.exe
### END INIT INFO

#GLOBAL VARIABLES
ROOT_ID=0                                   # Root ID
USER_ID=$(id -u)                            # User ID of the user who is running the script
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin          # 
APP_PATH=/usr/bin/NetworkServer.exe         # The path where the Visitor APP is located
RETURN_VALUE=0                              # The return value
APP_PID=`ps -ef | grep $APP_PATH | grep -v grep | awk '{print$2}'`      # The Visitor APP PID 

. /lib/lsb/init-functions



do_start (){
# if it is running do nothing
if [ -n "$APP_PID" ]; then
    echo "The visitord service is already running (pid $APP_PID)"
    RETURN_VALUE=1
else
    if [ -f $APP_PATH ]; then
        mono $APP_PATH &
        APP_PID=$!
        echo "The visitord service is running (pid $APP_PID)"
        RETURN_VALUE=0
    else
        echo "The VisitorApp doesn't exist, or its location has been changed"
        RETURN_VALUE=1
    fi
fi

}

case "$1" in
  start)
    do_start
    exit $RETURN_VALUE
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: visitord start|stop|restart|status" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac
```

This is the NetworkServer.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace VisitorApp{

public class NetworkServer{

    private int port;
    private TcpListener tcpListener;

    public NetworkServer(int port){
        this.port = port;
    }

    public  void Start(){

        TextWriter tw = File.AppendText("/var/www/Visitor/log.log");

        try{
            this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(this.port);
            this.tcpListener.Start();
            tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+" >> Server started");
        }catch{
            tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+" >> The port "+this.port+" is already in use");
            return;
        }finally{
            tw.Close(); 
        }

        int clientNo=0;

        while(true){


            System.Net.Sockets.Socket socketForClient = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
            clientNo++;

            if (socketForClient.Connected){
                tw = File.AppendText("/var/www/Visitor/log.log");
                tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+" >> Client["+clientNo+"] is connected");
                NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(socketForClient);
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(networkStream);

                string url;
                try{

                    url = streamReader.ReadLine();
                    tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+" >> URL from the Client: "+url);
        //The execution stops here!!!!!!
                    new VisitorWindow("Visitor App",url);
                    tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+" >> An open window has been closed");
                }catch{
                    tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+" The Client didn't send a URL");

                }finally{
                    tw.Close();
                    socketForClient.Close();
                    networkStream.Close();
                    streamReader.Close();
                }


            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main(){

        new Thread(new ThreadStart(
            delegate {
                new NetworkServer(9898).Start();
            })).Start();
    }
}
}
```

This is the Client.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Client{

public class Client{

    private TcpClient clientSocket;
    private string server;
    private int port;
    private string url;

    public Client(string server, int port, string url){
        this.clientSocket = new TcpClient();
        this.server = server;
        this.port = port;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void Connect(){

        try{
            this.clientSocket.Connect(this.server,this.port);
        }catch{
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect to server: "+this.server+" port: "+this.port);
            return;
        }
        NetworkStream serverStream = this.clientSocket.GetStream();
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(serverStream);

        try{

            streamWriter.WriteLine(url);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }catch{

            Console.WriteLine("Exception writing to the Server");

        }finally{
            this.clientSocket.Close();
            serverStream.Close();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

    }

    public static void Main(){
        Client c = new Client("localhost",9898,"http://www.stackoverflow.com");
        c.Connect();
    }
}
}
```

VisitorWindow.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Gtk;
using WebKit;

namespace VisitorApp{

public class VisitorWindow {

    private string windowName;
    private string url;
    private Gtk.Window window;
    public TextWriter tw;

    public VisitorWindow(string windowName, string url){
        this.windowName = windowName;
        this.url = url;

        try{
            this.CreateWindow();
        }catch(Exception exc){
            this.tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+" >> "+exc.ToString());
        }finally{
            this.tw.Close();    
        }
    }

    public void CreateWindow(){
        this.tw = File.AppendText("/var/www/Visitor/log.log");
        this.tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+" >> Before Application.Init");
        Application.Init ();
        this.tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+" >> After Application.Init");

        //Set the graphical properties of the window
        this.window = new Gtk.Window (this.windowName);
        this.tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+" >> After Gtk.Window (this.windowName)");
        window.SetDefaultSize(1000,800);
        this.tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+" >> After window.SetDefaultSize(1000,800)");
        //window.FullScreen();

        //Adding events for actions
        window.DeleteEvent += new DeleteEventHandler (OnWindowDelete);
        this.tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+" >> After DeleteEventHandler (OnWindowDelete)");
        //Create the embed content
        ScrolledWindow scroll = new ScrolledWindow ();
        this.tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+" >> After new scroll");

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        this.tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+" >> After new WebView();");

        webView.Open (this.url);
        this.tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+" >>  webView.Open (this.url);");
        scroll.Add (webView);  
        this.tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+" >>  scroll.Add (webView);");
        window.Add (scroll);
        this.tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+" >>  window.Add (scroll);");

        window.ShowAll();
        this.tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+" >>  window.ShowAll()");
        Application.Run ();
        this.tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now+" >>  Application.Run ");
    }
    void OnWindowDelete (object obj, DeleteEventArgs args){
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
}
```

Log file:

```
04/24/2012 08:23:27 >> Server started
04/24/2012 08:24:56 >> Client[1] is connected
04/24/2012 08:24:56 >> URL from the Client: http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

There is no error in the log file, any exception is thrown, just it crashes...
Any help will be very useful!!

Comment: can you wrap the main loop in a try/catch and write it to a file?
I am guessing you are running into a permission issue because the service is being started by a user you do not expect, but the exception log would do you wonders.

Comment: I added some information that I omitted, I thought that it wasn't important but the execution stops when I try to make an instance of a class that I made with GTK and Webkit (I also updated the description of my problem)

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might help is you say when you try to connect a Client the program crashes. What is the error message?

The other thing I'd like to add is that your Client.cs doesn't feel right to me. It could just be me being fussy, but the Main method of the Client class creates an instance of itself. How do you create a Client object? You say the NetworkServer.exe is running when your Linux box starts it only crashes when you create a Client.

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a X Window up from a server - how would you know which display to connect to?

You'll need another client program, running within X, that connects to your server, and receives events, and that client GUI program can do stuff on the Linux desktop.

Consider a machine like [this](http://linuxgazette.net/124/smith.html) - a six-user multi-head system - how could your program know which display to connect to? No daemon started by init - from SysV dirs, or upstart, can know which display to use. Therefore you need a program started on one of your machine's users' desktops, as you may be suggesting with `xinit`. That can either be your entire program, or just a client for your daemon, either should be possible.

Comment: I think that the problem is that the deamon is executed in a runlevel that doesnt have the Graphic environment set, and when the server tries to launch the window some dependencies are not ready or were loaded after the deamon. I know that in ubuntu runlevels  2,3,4 and 5 are the same (usually in linux runlevel 5 is when gnome is set but it's not in ubuntu), what I'll try to do is to launch my script in **xinit**...

Comment: @user1352319 It's not a matter of the dependencies not running - anything started by the runlevels init or upstart is not going to have sufficient information to connect to a `DISPLAY`, you need to have a program running in the X session in order to reliably display a program in the X GUI.